# Change product view to 2-columns

Tags: magento2

I want that all product's view have the right column, i don't know if it can be done in the admin, but if the response is how to made it by code, i appreciate all the path to the files.

And i want the correct answer, no a code that do the work but in the worst way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change layout of the **catalog_product_view.xml**

Override this layout in your custom module or theme and do the below changes:

if you want to display product details page 2column right then change file is catalog_product_view.xml

set layout value **layout="2columns-right"** inside  node.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-right" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
```

**File path for layout change** -

> app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

Comment: but, where? i tried in :app/design/frontend/{{Company}}/{{theme}}/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

Comment: And then, cache:flush, setup:static-content:deploy...?

Comment: No, maybe i need some content in <page>?
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-right" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
 <container>...</container>
</page>

Comment: forgive the last comment, i had a problem upload the file, the code works