# Magento 2 - Change product view to 2-columns left

Tags: magento-2.1.7

I was trying to change **product page** layout to **2 columns** left so that the left navigagion menu could be visible at entire magneto2 store. 
when I change Product page Layout at Product Edit page -> Design -> Layout to '2 columns with leftbar' I get the error :

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: Illegal offset type in /vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/CategoryRepository.php on line 133

Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: Illegal offset type in /vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/CategoryRepository.php on line 133
#0 /vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/CategoryRepository.php(133): Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(2, 'Illegal offset ...', '/...', 133, Array)
#1 /vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/ListProduct.php(114): Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository->get(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor))
#2 /vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/ListProduct.php(176): Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct->_getProductCollection()
#3 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(658): Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct->_before
```

ToHtml()
 . . .

I also found similar question at [Change product view to 2-columns](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/155707/change-product-view-to-2-columns) .

By referring this I copied `Magento_Catalog` folder to

```
app/design/frontend/Magento/luma
```

from

```
vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma
```

and changed to `layout="2columns-left"`. But it didn't work. Please advice.

Thanks in advance !